# ISERIES OS/400 error checking

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

can some help me find any errors in this PGM. It doesnt compile for me

```
         PGM                                                     

         DCL        VAR(&LIB) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10) VALUE('A2LIB14')  
         DCL        VAR(&MSG) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(80) VALUE('*** S T + 
                      O P ***       READ YOU HAVE READ ALL +       
                      INSTRUCTIONS CAREFULLY')                     
         SNDMSG     MSG(MSG) TOUSR(*REQUESTER)                    
         DSPMSG                                                    
         ADDLIBLE   LIB(&LIB)                                      
         STRDFU     OPTION(*SELECT) FILE(&LIB/TVSHOWSL) MBR(*FIRST)
         CRTPF      FILE(TVSHOWS) RCDLEN(10)                 
         DSPOBJD    OBJ(TVSHOWSL1) OBJTYPE(*LF)               
         WRKJOB     JOB(**)                                        
         ENDPGM
```

Comment: The compiler error messages say what's wrong. Typing or copy/pasting the commands on a command line will tell you what's wrong. If you even try to enter the commands in a source editor, the editor will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. `*LF` is not a valid OBJTYPE parameter on the [DSPOBJD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/dspobjd.htm) command.
2. `**` is not a valid JOB parameter on the [WRKJOB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/wrkjob.htm) command.